# Store value in ViewState from Session

Tags: c#, session, viewstate

I stored a value in `Session` in a page (**C#**). I retrieve the Session value in another page and store the same in `ViewState`. After that, I cleared the Session and performed some operation (button events, etc.) using  the ViewState within the page.

But, after storing the value from Session to ViewState, if **I refresh the browser, the ViewState value is not available**. Because, it tried to get the value from Session, but it was cleared already (first time).

I need some guidance/suggestion to do that in proper way.

Comment: What exactly is your problem? Is it that ViewState is not available? Do you ask for other place to store value?

Comment: Why would you want to delete some value from the session? If you put something in the Session object you want it there, if not, don't put it there in the first place.

Comment: In page load I stored the session value to viewstate and clear the session. Because I don't want to keep the session anymore. But if I refresh the browser, viewstate value not exist. Any other way to keep the value...?

Answer (score 1):

When you refresh the browser the previous request will be executed again.
At this juncture the session variable is cleared (since you are doing it after saving viewstate).
Other approach would be to pass the data using query string between pages if you want it to persist (without session). I think cookies also might work here.

Normally session will be safer and persistent.

Comment: I cannot use query string and cookies for that. Actually I stored `List<object>` in session. If no other way to do that, I will keep the session. But I need to clear the session in that page. That is the problem I have. Thanks for your suggestion... :)

Comment: you can then try to save the values in a hidden field. This will be available on the new page inside the request object. It will also be available if you "Refresh" the page. But on page post back the values will go away. You can use view state on postback.
Any specific reason why storing in session is not an option ?